# Добавить кнопку next&last

Tags: slider

```
function next(arr) {
      var max = arr.length - 1,
        i = -1;
      return function () {
        i = i < max ? i + 1 : 0;
        return arr[i];
      };
    }
    jQuery(function () {
      var slider = next($('#start>div.go'));
      var curent;
      setInterval(function () {
        if (curent) $(curent).hide();
        curent = slider();
        $(curent).show();
      }, 3000);
    });
```

По очереди меняет видимость 3х div.go по циклу 3000ms.

Мне бы хотелось бы сделать два дива - .last & .next, - по клику на который бы происходило действие, отображающее предыдущий. div.go считаю от того div.go, который сейчас виден.

Ну, если проще, то кнопка назад и вперед. И все.

Помогите дописать код, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, добавить некий идентефикатор, который будет уникальным для каждого дива слайдера.

При смене видимости дивов заносить в переменную идентефикатор текущего отображаемого дива.

Ну а дальше, просто напросто, назначить события, которые будут сменять видимость дивов, отталкиваясь от этих идентефикаторов.